# MS Access export report to pdf

Tags: ms-access, pdf, macros, report

I have a form with a button that should allow the frontend user to export a list to a PDF format. However when the export begins the parameter is asked for which appears to open the report.

By it automatically calling the report to export it opens up the report and parameter without saving and closing which is a conflict to it generating the report so it has an error.

How can I make it export with a parameter first? It appears it would have to temporarily open the report then close it after saving.  However I'm not sure how I would do that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the code that you use to export?

Comment: does this help at all?: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/902555-how-export-report-parameters-pdf

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this easily since the file output is not necessary you may leave the output field blank in the macro form. It will prompt you immediately with a dialogue box. Intuitively since the field is there it is tempting to fill it out and get this error. I suggest studying up on your macros before trying to resolve an issue...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff197066.aspx